# Rails STI build relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

I'm using STI (correctly, I promise!) for one relation of an object:

```
class Walrus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :bubbles
end

class Bubbles < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :walrus
  before_save :set_origin

  private

  def set_origin
    self.type = walrus.state ? "Bubbles::#{walrus.state}" : 'Bubbles'
  end
end

class Bubbles::OfMind < Bubbles
  def tango
  end
end
```

Now if I build a new relation, the class isn't set correctly:

```
harold = Walrus.new(state: 'OfMind')
harold.build_bubbles.save!
harold.bubbles
  # => returns instance of Bubbles, not Bubbles::OfMind
harold.bubbles.tango
  # NoMethodError
```

The Bubbles object cannot magically become a Bubbles::OfMind, but until the relation is of the correct type, the correct functionality does not exist.

Comment: You might have to spell it out, because I don't see a hint of STI here. I see three bare classes with no inheritance at all. Is `Walrus` supposed to be the superclass?

Comment: Added the inheritance

Comment: What is the build_bubbles method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before addressing STI, watch out for model names and associations that break convention. I understand that you've chosen these class names for the sake of demonstration, but since you are running and testing this code, erratic behavior is no surprise.

Model class names should be **singlular** and sensible. Change the superclass to `Bubble`, and the subclass to something that refers to a variation of a bubble,  such as `BigBubble`.

`has_one` associations must use **singular** model names as well: `has_one :bubble`.

Note: When Rails encounters a namespaced model, it expects the corresponding controller and view files to be namespaced as well, nested directories and all. It gets messy in a hurry. Best to avoid namespaces unless *absolutely* necessary.

---

Builder methods are a misuse of STI. Builder methods **attempt to instantiate the superclass** and manually assign it a type. This conflicts with Rails' built-in management of STI classes, hence no support for it.

STI superclasses are abstract classes that **should never be instantiated**. When working with STI, you must only interact with a subclass. All methods of a superclass are exposed in the subclasses, so there's no reason to touch a superclass object... unless to modify the `type` attribute which violates Rails' convention. If you absolutely must manipulate the superclass, STI shouldn't be used.

Properly done, you should create a subclass object directly with a manual association:

```
harold = Walrus.create!
BigBubble.create!(:walrus_id => harold.id)

harold.bubble
  # => returns instance of BigBubble

harold.bubble.tango
  # => true
```

Although not as elegant as a builder method, this way is proper and it works. Those blogs trying to solve namespaced STI association wonkiness ([ahem...](http://simple10.com/rails-3-sti/)) are attempting to force behavior that isn't appropriate for STI to begin with. Proper usage of STI involves adopting the design guideline, "*don't mess with the superclass*."

Comment: What if the subclass needs to be calculated? So you have BigBubble and SmallBubble and which one is associated to a given walrus is based on the Walrus' current age? I guess calculate that first and instantiate the correct subclass?

Comment: Right. Determine the appropriate subclas first, then instantiate it. There is no in-between class for the interim. Another way to look at it is to swap out BigBubble and SmallBubble for other classes, say Integer and Hash.